# Union type with optional keys

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have two types `A` and `B`. Both have `k` as a common but with different types. But A got an additional field `j`. When I union both and use them like this:

```
type A = {
    k?: string;
    j?: boolean
}
type B = {
    k?: number;
}
type C = B | A;

function D({ k, j }: C) {
    console.log(j)
}
```

I am getting the TypeScript error saying `Property 'j' does not exist on type 'B'.`

Can someone explain this behavior?

Comment: Object types in TS are open, not sealed; extra properties are generally allowed, so a value of type `B` might have a `j` property of any type at all, as shown [in this example](https://tsplay.dev/w1xqlW).  Does that fully address the question? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Typescript does what it should do, you won't be able to just destruct  as you currently trying to do

Comment: Since you dont provide any value for "j" typescript is infering C type is B

Comment: @BrunoMiguel Maybe I should have phrased the question better. What if I am using the type `C` as a function argument and try to destruct the `j`. BTW I have updated the question.

Comment: When you do: type C = B | A; you are really saying C can be of type either B | A. Now on your function declaration: function D({ k, j }: C), you are saying the the input type must be of type C. Since it can be of type C, it can be either A or B. Typescript cant be sure if the object you are passing in has the property J. you could pass in an object of type A in the case it would work, but you can also pass in an object of type B and in that case you would not have "j" property in it. So since both A or B can be pass in, typescript cant be sure that "j" will be present.

Comment: Maybe you want an intersection type and not an union: type C = B & A;